# 5 Images not in line

Tags: css

I have a DIV which is 900% wide, I'm trying to display 5 images in a line but the 5th one always wraps around and I can't work out why?

I'm well under 900px with my 5 images.

```css
ul{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
li{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  list-style:none;
}

.photo-preview{
  width:178px;
  margin:0px;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}

.bottom-row{
  width:900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-row">
  <ul>
        <li class="photo-preview"><img src="photo/2.JPG"></li>   
        <li class="photo-preview"><img src="photo/2.JPG"></li>
        <li class="photo-preview"><img src="photo/2.JPG"></li>   
        <li class="photo-preview"><img src="photo/2.JPG"></li>   
        <li class="photo-preview"><img src="photo/2.JPG"></li>                             
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `900%` wide....? Why would you want to do that? If you mean pixels, I suggest to spend more time on the question to make sure its clear. Because well.... I am completely missing the HTML? Could just be me, but I could grab my magic 8 ball and foresee the future of this question if you don't edit the question to include that.

Comment: I think he meant 900px ;)

Answer (score 3):

Most browsers add a little bit of space between inline list items. YOu can use this funky formatting hack to stop that happening. Or you could just float them left if that suits your needs.

```
<div class="bottom-row">
  <ul>
    <li class="photo-preview"><img src="photo/2.JPG"></li><li class="photo-preview">
    <img src="photo/2.JPG"></li><li class="photo-preview">
    <img src="photo/2.JPG"></li><li class="photo-preview">
    <img src="photo/2.JPG"></li><li class="photo-preview">
    <img src="photo/2.JPG"></li>                             
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Different browsers, different default settings. And a `ul` wil display each `li` on a new vertical space unless you change the css display attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! 
Like @WizardCoder said, there will always be a tiny bit of spacing between images but a -1px will fix it for you!

**EDIT**: I have tailored the question to be exactly the code you posted on JSFiddle. Anyways,

1. You need to have your `display: inline` on the `li` item.
2. You need the class `photo-preview` on the `img` and **not** on the `li` item.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}

.photo-preview {
  width: 178px;
  margin: -1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.bottom-row {
  width: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-row">
  <ul>
    <li><img class="photo-preview" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Octicons-mark-github.svg"></li>   
    <li><img class="photo-preview" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Octicons-mark-github.svg"></li>
    <li><img class="photo-preview" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Octicons-mark-github.svg"></li>   
    <li><img class="photo-preview" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Octicons-mark-github.svg"></li>   
    <li><img class="photo-preview" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Octicons-mark-github.svg"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```